# Linq to Entities LIKE '[A-G]%' query

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I'm trying to recreate some SQL queries I have into L2E statements.  One of the queries is:

```
SELECT TOP 25 itms.[StringValue]
      ,itms.[Name]
      ,itms.[Picture]
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[Items] AS itms
  WHERE itms.StringValue LIKE '[A-G]%'
```

I am given a start `char` (A in this case) and an end `char` (G) and I need to pull all of the items whos `StringValue` starts with a `char` between Start and Finish.

My first try was to see if L2E would just give it to me with this query:

```
items = from i in items
        where i.StringValue.StartsWith("[" + refinement.Value + "]")
        select i;
```

I figured it wouldn't work, but it was worth a try.

Comment: Try concatenating your like condition prior to building the query: string likeCondition = "[" + "....; >> where i.StringValue.StratsWith(likeCondition)

Comment: @Polity:  thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that and still nothing.  I'm seeing in the generated SQL statement a line that says `WHERE [Limit1].[StringValue] LIKE @p__linq__2 ESCAPE N'~'` at the spot where the starts with is.  I'm thinking that the `ESCAPE` is the problem?

Comment: On further inspection, `@p__linq__2` = `~[A-G]%`.  So, how do I unescape it?

Comment: http://jendaperl.blogspot.com/2011/02/like-in-linq-to-entities.html this might be where the solution is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options that should work:

1) if you know the filter is just based on the first char, then you could do something like:

```
var startChar = 'A';
var endChar = 'G';

// other options, but you get the point
var validStartChars = Enumerable.Range(0, 26)
    .Select(i => (char)('A' + i))
    .Where(c => c >= startChar && c <= endChar)
    .ToArray();

var matches = items.Where(i => validStartChars.Contains(i.StringValue[0]));
```

similarly, you could fetch the first char and just do the greater/lesser checks in the Where clause (if it's always a range like that)

2) if you want, you can still use sql to query with L2E, just use the ExecuteStoreQuery and let it return the entities back for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx

If you want the returned entities to be tracked, make sure to call the overload that lets you specify the entity set name:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487226.aspx

Comment: L2E doesn't recognize `get_char(int)` but I like the idea! L2E errored out on the `i.StringValue[0]` part...

Comment: Ah, perhaps i.StringValue.Substring(0,1)?  Would likely need the char array as string array instead

Answer (score 0):

That should really have worked so I'm not entirely sure why it hasn't.  Worth checking that refinement.Value comes from somewhere sensible and not directly another LINQ to SQL query.

In addition to that though, there is the [SQLMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.aspx) class which offers a great many of the facilities which would be available in SQL when writing LINQ to SQL queries (note that it won't work with LINQ to objects Queries).  You could therefore use the SQLMethods Like method and give it your original LIKE statement.

Comment: Thanks, the values from the refinement are sensible (like "A-G"). The SQLMethods aren't available for L2E so they don't work :(